# Change the OS X Dock background

Tags: macos, dock

I find that with some wallpapers, the Dock that ships with Leopard can be way too bright and stand out more than desired. How can I change the appearance of the Dock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[LeopardDocks](http://leoparddocks.com/index.php) is a great website that has lots and lots of different replacement dock backgrounds. To use the files the website provides, just use their [LeopardDocks App](http://leoparddocks.com/Leopard_Docks_App.php).

Comment: I downloaded one of the docks, but all i got was a folder full of .pngs. Is there a program to do it for me?

Answer (score 8):

I've also had problems with the default Leopard Dock. If you use the following commands in the terminal, you can get a different, 2-dimensional dock:

```
coputername:~ user$ defaults write com.apple.dock no-glass -boolean YES
coputername:~ user$ killall Dock
```

[image: 2D Dock Image]

If you change your mind, you can restore the 3-dimensional dock with the following commands:

```
coputername:~ user$ defaults write com.apple.dock no-glass -boolean NO
coputername:~ user$ killall Dock
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best combo is [Candybar](http://www.panic.com/candybar/) and various docks from [MacThemes](http://macthemes2.net) or the [Iconfactory](http://iconfactory.com/search/freeware/dock). Candybar is simple, quick, and effective.

You might want to look at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/5433/are-there-ways-to-tweak-the-ui-on-a-mac-os-x/) about tweaking the UI in OS X.

Answer (score 0):

[ClearDock](http://unsanity.com/haxies/cleardock)

Comment: "ClearDock currently does not work on Mac OS X 10.5.x. More Info."