# Where is the dock background image located in OSX?

Tags: macos, dock

Just so you know, I have seen the other similar posts, like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/4308/change-the-os-x-dock-background).

Anyway, do you know where the background image is located in OSX Mountain Lion?  Or at least a way to change the dock background image and/or color WITHOUT a third party application?

In all of the other posts like this, people have suggested things like CandyBar, but I need a solution without that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parts of the Dock background (at least the "plain" one mentioned in the linked question) are stored in separate files with all other Dock resources in `/System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources`.

If your Dock is on the left, check out the image files whose names start with *left*, the separator between applications and documents is in the files with names starting with *separator*, etc.

Unfortunately, it appears that the yellow area is the extend of what can be changed by editing these files.

[image: Yellow Dock outline]

There doesn't seem to be a "center" image. [Some people](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1495519) even resort to patching the actual Dock program (you should have a backup before doing this, just in case), as the color information now seems to be part of the Dock's code.

Answer (score 0):

Mountain lion renders the dock through code; it no longer uses .PNGs to render it.

As of now the only way I have found to change the color of the Mountain Lion dock is to use [dockmod](http://spyresoft.com/) which is an app that costs 8 dollars.

I like having a darker dock but seeing as it is August and mavericks is supposed to be out in the fall, I am not sure if its a good idea paying for multiple licenses to modify the docks on my two macs.